# Python file not debugging in vscode docker container

Tags: docker, debugging, visual-studio-code

Opened VSCode. Started container by docker extension. Attached visual studio code with container. Start debugging but nothing shows on terminal. Added break points, debugging not started. Debugging palette appears for a while.[Start debugging but nothing shows on terminal. Added break points, debugging not started. Debugging palette appears for a while.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ueocz.gif)
Tried reinstall, restart laptop, remote python extension in prerelease version.

```
**VScode**
Version: 1.69.1 (user setup)  
Commit: b06ae3b2d2dbfe28bca3134cc6be65935cdfea6a  
Date: 2022-07-12T08:21:24.514Z  
Electron: 18.3.5  
Chromium: 100.0.4896.160 
Node.js: 16.13.2 V8: 10.0.139.17-electron.0  
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
```

Python Extension in docker container: v2022.10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is caused by python extension(microsoft) in container. Downgraded python extension from v2022.10.1 to v2022.8.0 in container extensions. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem

I solved it by opening my folder in VS Code.

1. File -> Open Folder
2. A window will pop up, navigate to your project folder
   [image]
3. After that, start debugging, it should be wokring now.
   If debugging is working, it will pop up a window like this.
   [image]